Я хочу получить свойства кнопки нажатых форм в PHP
Я пытаюсь создать редактор заметок на PHP и MySQL. Но я столкнулся с проблемой. Заметок очень много, и чтобы выбрать нужную, я решил добавить идентификатор, дату, текст и заголовок в свойства кнопки, но я не знаю, как получить данные конкретной заметки.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id_user = ".$_SESSION['id_user']."";
                    if($result = mysqli_query($mySql, $sql)){
                      $results='';
                       foreach($result as $row) {
                           $results.='<section class="notes-section section" id="notesCard">
                                         <div id= "noteContent" class="note-content">
                                             <div class="note-h2"><h2 id="headingH2">'.$row['heading'].'</h2></div>
                                             <div class="note-text"><p id="textArea">'.$row['text_content'].'</p></div>
                                             <div class="note-panel">
                                                 <label id="dateNotes" for="">'.$row['date'].'</label>
                                                 <form action="editNote.php" name="" method="post">
                                                    <button name="editNotes" id="edit" class="insert-btn btn" value="'.$row['id_notes'].'">Изменить</button>
                                                    <button name="deleteNotes" class="delete-btn btn" value="'.$row['id_notes'].'">Удалить</button>
                                                    </form>
                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                                    </section>';
                         }
                      echo $results;
                    } else {
                      echo "Что-то пошло не так...";
                    }

                    if (isset($_POST['deleteNotes']) and is_numeric($_POST['deleteNotes'])) {
                      $delete = $_POST['deleteNotes'];
                      if ($mySql -> query("DELETE FROM `notes` WHERE `id_notes` = '$delete'")) {
                        
                        echo '<script>window.location = "./notes.php"</script>';
                      }
                    }

Я пытался сделать всё через js, но у меня недостаточно знаний для этого
Извините за плохой английский, Google Translate все перевел

Покажи уже итоговый html

Согласно спецификации HTML, элемент с указанным id внутри DOM-документа может быть ТОЛЬКО один.
Исходя из этого, для каждого элемента, где есть тег id, добавляем в него номер записи из БД.
Таким образом, после отправки формы, к вам будут приходить переменные вида editNotes<номер_записи_из_таблицы>, deleteNotes<номер_записи_из_таблицы>.
foreach($result as $row) {
    $results.="<section class='notes-section section' id='notesCard".$row['id_notes']."'>\n".
              "    <div id='noteContent".$row['id_notes']."' class='note-content'>\n".
              "        <div class='note-h2'><h2 id='headingH2".$row['id_notes']."'>".$row['heading']."</h2></div>\n".
              "        <div class='note-text'><p id='textArea".$row['id_notes']."'>".$row['text_content']."</p></div>\n".
              "        <div class='note-panel'>\n".
              "            <label id='dateNotes".$row['id_notes']."' for=''>".$row['date']."</label>\n".
              "            <form action='editNote.php' name='' method='post'>\n".
              "                <button name='editNotes' id='editNotes".$row['id_notes']."' class='insert-btn btn'>Изменить</button>\n".
              "                <button name='deleteNotes' id='deleteNotes".$row['id_notes']."' class='delete-btn btn'>Удалить</button>\n".
              "            </form>\n".
              "        </div>\n".
              "    </div>\n".
              "</section>\n";
}

Далее перебираем таки переменные и извлекаем из них номер ИД записи:
foreach( array_keys($_POST) as $key) {
    if ( mb_substr( $key,0,9) == 'editNotes' ) {
        $id = mb_sustr( $key, 9, mb_strlen( $key) - 8 );
        if (is_numeric( $id ) && intval( $id) > 0 ) {
            //edit
        }
    }
    if ( mb_substr( $key,0,11) == 'deleteNotes' ) {
        $id = mb_sustr( $key, 12, mb_strlen( $key) - 11 );
        if (is_numeric( $id ) && intval( $id) > 0 ) {
            //delete
        }
    }
}

Вариант 2.
Добавьте внутрь каждой формы скрытое поле, содержащее id записи, и после отправки формы берите его значение.
